# Using links (link_rss field) as the source for fetch_feed

Tags: feed

I am trying to display feeds from a couple of my blogs using the build in function fetch_feed() however I stumbled across a few problems.

I am storing the rss urls in the links section and will be calling the link_rss as the input for fetch_feed(). I know that I would have to deal with an array, perhaps nested arrays??

Can someone be kind enough to give me a way of pulling all the link_rss fields into one single variable which can be use for fetch_feed()??

Having the variable in the form of an array would be great so I can just plug it in to the function like so fetch_feed($variable).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Possible, only I am not entirely sure about specifics of looping through multi-feed SimplePie object. Customize [`get_bookmarks()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bookmarks) call to query for links you need.

```
$bookmarks = get_bookmarks();
$feeds = array();

foreach($bookmarks as $bookmark)
    if($bookmark->link_rss)
        $feeds[] = $bookmark->link_rss;

$items = fetch_feed($feeds);
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

fetch_feed() expects an URL, so you basically need to create a URL that will return link_rss data in form of RSS-Feed while being requested via HTTP. That looks too complicated in my eyes.

Filtering the fetch_feed() function is too complicated as well. Probably injecting the feed using the data: url scheme might do some magic, but I assume that SimplePie might not deal with that.

Comment: Nope, `fetch_feed()` uses `SimplePie->set_feed_url()` that accepts mixed input of single URL or array of URLs.

Comment: @Rarst: You see some chance to make use of that for something usefull? I did understand the asker that he wants to have a feed consisting of his links and not the feeds on his links.

Comment: ehm, I interpreted question as how to produce combined feed of several sources. I don't see anything about producing feed in question, only about fetching?..

Comment: @rarst: well then, you answer should be doing the job. I might just got the question wrong.